# Sample SD vs Population SD

Tags: statistics

Ok, so it maybe a dumb question, but why are population SD and sample SD different in the following set? Isn't the sample equal to population here?

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
Sample SD = 2.16
Population SD = 2
```

Further, why is N-1 used in formula for Sample SD?
Is $\mu$ equal to $\bar x$?

Comment: The idea is that if you need to estimate the mean using the sample mean, then that "uses up" one of your points.  As a rule, if you are working with data or an application of statistics, use the sample mean.  Use the population when you are working from theory or model where you can generate the entire population from the model.

Answer (score 0):

Sample standard deviation is an *estimator* for the population standard deviation. It does not mean they will coincide in all cases.

In addition, the $N-1$ correction is used to make the estimator *unbiased*, i.e. to achieve that the expected value of the estimator be what it is supposed to be estimating...

Comment: The 0.16 difference is due to n-1, right? Population mean and sample mean after still same ?

Comment: @AnvitGarg yes, that is correct